# Facing error while creating .doc file using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

While creating a `.DOC` file using apache POI libraries, I face the error

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException at
> CreateDocument.main(CreateDocument.java:12)"

I would appreciate any help.

[image]

Comment: How are you managing your dependencies?

Comment: Have added the following jar files: poi-3.17,poi-examples-3.17,poi-excelant-3.17, poi-ooxml-3.17, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17, poi-scratchpad-3.17 to the project. Do i need to add anything else also? Used the below steps listed to add JAR files "https://netbeans.org/kb/74/java/project-setup.html"

Comment: What happens if you [follow the Apache POI documentation and add the dependencies that Apache POI is listed needing](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the following on my machine with no problems (the document is created):

```
public static void main(String...args) {

    try {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/home/william/Documents/test.docx");
        document.write(fos);

        document.close();

        System.out.println("Document created successfully");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Document not created");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I used gradle to manage my dependencies. Not all the dependencies you mentioned in your comment are necessary for this example. In particular you only need the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.17'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.17'
}
```

What build tool are you using? Maven? Gradle?

Some comments on your original code:

1- Your try block doesn't have a catch block following it for exceptions. Consider catching the exception and displaying a meaningful error to the user if document creation fails. In my example I just printed the stacktrace but if this is a web app or a gui you would probably want to show the user a message.

2- You don't close the `document` after writing, which causes a resource leak.

The exception you are getting is because the class `XmlException` cannot be found. This class is in the `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar` (or similar, this is the latest version at the time of writing).

Try adding the dependency to your build script

```
compile group: 'org.apache.xmlbeans', name: 'xmlbeans', version: '2.6.0'
```

Comment: I am using Netbeans. Was not adding the dependency properly. It's resolved now. Thanks!